# How to Properly Get Nested Folders to Render in MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

I've got the traditional website with all MVC 5 working as expected, everything renders correctly and works fine.

I've added a Dashboard and this dashboard I am attempting to set to folder structure up to where it is isolated from the rest of the MVC 5 C# website; however, I'm receiving a Server Error stating that the layout engine cannot find my Partial views.

Now, when the view itself loads this is passing the test and is indeed returning the correct view, the problem is coming in when the layout engine cannot locate the nested Partial Views.

I am lost on this one due to the fact that I do not have a MVC 5 full understanding.

Now, like mentioned before everything works perfectly in regards to the out of the box folder structure but when I create a nested folder and put Partial  Views the MVC 5 engine cannot locate these nested Partial Views.

The reason being nesting these Partial Views is obvious I am separating the actual traditional website from the User Dashboard views.

When I click the action link pointing to the Index file this works but when the body, The View, trys to render it cannot find the nested Partial Views.

What am I missing here? I hope that I am providing enough information that make answering this question as easy as possible.

**Loading the Actual User Dashboard Index Works**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_Layout_Dashboard.cshtml";
}
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
```

**Loading the actual Partials is where the Server says NO NO, you're not doing this correctly.**

[image: This Snapshot Is The _Layout]

**Here is the Exact Server Error, Please Advise Me On The Proper Way to Implement this.**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The partial view '~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard

Source Error:


Line 26: <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>*@
Line 27: <body>
Line 28:     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard")
Line 29:     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialLeftNav_Dashboard")
Line 30:     @RenderBody()


Source File: D:\Users\Erik\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BuilderBits\BuilderBits\Views\Shared\UserDashboard\_Layout_Dashboard.cshtml    Line: 28

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard]
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext, String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +327
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName) +32
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_UserDashboard__Layout_Dashboard_cshtml.Execute() in D:\Users\Erik\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BuilderBits\BuilderBits\Views\Shared\UserDashboard\_Layout_Dashboard.cshtml:28
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) +232
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765045
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to include the partial view using `@Html.Partial("_PartialHeader_Dashboard")` , MVC framework will try to load the partial views from the below locations as per the MVC conventions.

1. `~/Views/DirectoryWithYourCurrentControllerName/`
2. `~/Views/Shared/`

The framework has no idea your partial view is inside a sub directory unless you tell the framework to do so by extending the view engine and specifying the view file location(`ViewLocationFormats`). All you need to do is add your custom location.

You have 2 options

Call the partial view with the directory name (which is under `shared`)

```
@Html.Partial("UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard")
```

**Or**

Use the full file path

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/UserDashboard/_PartialHeader_Dashboard.cshtml")
```

But a better option is to consider [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas). Areas are present for logically keeping things (controllers/ views etc) together.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and can you give me a link explaining the areas.